# Difference in LoadingPivotItem and SelectionChanged

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have four PivotItems in a Pivot. I'm loading data in each PivotItem when it comes to view. I'm using the Pivot.SelectionChanged event, like so:

```
private void PivotSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
switch(mypivot.SelectedIndex)
{
case 0:
//load items for PivotItem 0
.......
.......
}
}
```

However, I see that there is also a LoadingPivotItem event, that can be used in similar way.
What is difference between these two methods? Is one more efficient than other?

Answer (score 0):

LoadingPivotItem means you can manipulate the content before it is displayed. Additional information here => [LoadingPivot](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/08/12/Windows-Phone-Pivot-and-loading-content.aspx)

Comment: but I can do the same with SelectionChanged too, right?

Comment: If i understand correctly, when you use LoadingPivotItem, you can load data before pivot item is display So you can use asynchone methode. When selectionchanged event is fire, pivot item is also display. It's the only difference i think.